# Format units with symbolic exponent in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I'm trying to format the equation for the Freundlich adsorption isotherm with an explanation of the corresponding dimensions:

[image: Freundlich]

Where [image: Gamma] is the adsorbed amount on the adsorption interface in mol/cm^2 and [image: C] is the concentration in the solution in mol/cm^3. The problem I run into is that the units of [image: kappa] depend on the shape parameter N.

When I try to format the units using `siunitx` as follows I get the error below:

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\si{\centi\metre\of{w}\tothe{N}\per\mol\tothe{N-1}\per\square\centi\metre\of{i}}
\end{document}
```

```
! Use of \??? doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \???  
      ! LaTeX Error: Unknown fp word N.
l.7 ...\mol\tothe{N-1}\per\square\centi\metre\of{i}}
                                                  
? 
! Emergency stop.
<argument> \???  
      ! LaTeX Error: Unknown fp word N.
l.7 ...\mol\tothe{N-1}\per\square\centi\metre\of{i}}
```

For now I can also format it in math mode using `\text` and explicit sub- and superscripts, but I would expect this to be handled by `siunitx`. It this at all possible or is my workaround the only option for this use case?

Comment: Please always provide full bit minimal examples, that makes it a lot easier for us to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `\tothe` is meant to be a real number: this reflects the fact that for example to combine exponents, `siunitx` needs to be able to 'do maths' with it. As such, for complex situations as this, you will need to format by hand.